# Override png file

Tags: java, nio

I want to override uploaded file. I tried this code:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, @RequestParam("id") Integer merchantId) throws Exception {
    try {
        File directory = new File(properties.getFileUploadDir(), merchantId.toString());
        directory.mkdirs();
        Path writeTargetPath = Files.write(
                Paths.get(directory.getAbsolutePath(), file.getOriginalFilename()).toAbsolutePath(),
                file.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW);
        Path fileToMovePath = Paths.get(properties.getFileUploadDir(), merchantId.toString(), "merchant_logo.png");
        Path movedPath = Files.move(writeTargetPath, fileToMovePath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        log.info("movedPath: {}", movedPath.toAbsolutePath());

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
                "Successfully uploaded '" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "'");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("IOException: {}", e);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Upload failed'" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "'");
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Successfully uploaded'" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "'");
```

}

But I get error:

```
java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: /opt/1/download.png
```

Do you know how I can override the old file with the same name every time when I upload a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html#CREATE_NEW) of `StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW` says:

> Create a new file, **failing if the file already exists.**

Use `StandardOpenOption.CREATE` in conjunction with `StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING` instead:

```
Path writeTargetPath = Files.write(
    Paths.get(directory.getAbsolutePath(), file.getOriginalFilename()).toAbsolutePath(),
    file.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
```